# Is there way to find a value / Text in a particular column of a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am relatively new to SQL, I have requirement like below.

I have the following tables.

**Table Name**: Name

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |
| 4 | DDD |
| 5 | EEE |

**Table Name**: Sprint

| Sprint Event | ID | Time | LAP | LIVE Status | Final Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 2018-11-02 15:28:11 | 0 | Started | Started |
| A1 | 1 | 2018-11-02 15:28:12 | 0 | Running | Running |
| A1 | 1 | 2018-11-02 15:28:12 | 1 | Running | Running |
| A1 | 1 | 2018-11-02 15:28:15 | 2 | Running | Running |
| A1 | 1 | 2018-11-02 15:28:16 | 3 | Running | Started |
| A1 | 1 | 2018-11-02 15:32:16 | 4 | Completed | Success |
| A1 | 2 | 2018-11-02 15:28:16 | 0 | Running | Running |
| A1 | 2 | 2018-11-02 15:28:17 | 1 | Running | Running |
| A1 | 2 | 2018-11-02 15:28:19 | 2 | Running | Started |
| A1 | 2 | 2018-11-02 15:36:19 | 3 | Running | Running |
| A1 | 2 | 2018-11-02 15:36:19 | 4 | Completed | Success |
| B1 | 3 | 2020-06-04 16:14:23 | 0 | Started | Started |
| B1 | 3 | 2020-06-04 16:14:23 | 0 | Running | Running |
| B1 | 3 | 2020-06-04 16:14:23 | 1 | Running | Running |
| B1 | 3 | 2020-06-04 16:14:27 | 2 | Running | Running |
| B1 | 3 | 2020-06-04 16:16:27 | 3 | Completed | Success |
| B1 | 4 | 2020-06-04 16:18:27 | 0 | Running | Running |
| B1 | 4 | 2020-06-04 16:14:27 | 1 | Running | Running |
| B1 | 4 | 2020-06-04 16:14:27 | 2 | ERROR | Running |
| B1 | 4 | 2020-06-04 16:14:29 | 3 | Running | Started |
| B1 | 4 | 2020-06-04 16:14:29 | 4 | Running | Running |
| B1 | 4 | 2020-06-04 16:23:30 | 5 | Completed | Success |

I also have multiple Sprint IDs like A1, B1, B2, C2 and so on.,

**Table Name**: State

| ID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NY |
| 2 | TX |
| 3 | AL |
| 4 | FL |
| 5 | IL |

Looking for result like this

| Sprint | Name | State | Laps (Count) | StartTime | EndTime | Status | Elapsed Time (Mins) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AAA | NY | 6 | 2018-11-02 15:28:11 | 2018-11-02 15:32:16 | Success | 4 |
| A1 | BBB | TX | 5 | 2018-11-02 15:28:16 | 2018-11-02 15:36:19 | Success | 8 |
| B1 | CCC | AL | 5 | 2020-06-04 16:14:23 | 2020-06-04 16:16:27 | Success | 2 |
| B2 | DDD | FL | 6 | 2020-06-04 16:14:27 | 2020-06-04 16:23:30 | Failed | 9 |

I am trying to query the sprint table for each ID's **start time**, **end time** and **status**. Status should be based on that particular's IDs last record's Final status value. If the last record's **Final status** value is Success for specific ID from start time to end time, I need to print Success. If any ID has any **ERROR** in LIVE status, regardless of their final status last record's value, I need to print **Failure**.

Here is the code which I tried

```
SELECT 
  N.Name, 
  
   st.state,
  Count (s1.Lap) as LapCount,
  MIN(s1.Time) AS [StartTime],
  MAX(s1.Time) AS [EndTime],
  case
  when (count (s2.lap) < 380 ) then 'Failed'
    else 'Succeeded'
  END AS Status
  datediff(MINUTE, min(s1.Time), max(s1.Time)) as 'RunTime in Mins'
FROM Sprint s1, Sprint s2
FULL outer join Name N on N.ID=s2.ID
FULL outer join State st on st.ID=s2.ID
WHERE s1.ID = s2.ID
  AND s2.Time = (SELECT 
                         MAX(Time) 
                       FROM Sprint s3
                       WHERE s2.ID = s3.ID) and
                       s1.Sprint='A1' 
GROUP BY N.Name,st.state
```

The issue with this, I am not able look for ERROR in Live Status column and print Failure. Also, I need to query multiple Sprint IDs and my where condition will be like where `s1.Sprint='A1' and s1.Sprint='B1'`.

Comment: You really should avoid comma delimited lists of tables. That works but the syntax is seriously outdated. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: What are those values in `TIME`? They are not valid times or dates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
actually it was like this in this format only 2019-05-28 16:05:53.700, however I changed it here for better readability.

Comment: But in changing for "readability" it has rendered the data useless. I can't put that into a table on my side to help with your query.

Comment: `23-05-21 2:01` is what I mean. What is this?

Comment: sorry about that. I modified the fields with right datetime field

Comment: There is no way you could get that result from that data (what is time anyway???). You should provide sample data and expected result that makes sense. This is more like an XY problem. You should also explain what do those Id stand for, the relations are totally obscure. What is the point of having old style self join in your query?

Comment: @Cetin I may have not presented my scenario very well, sorry about that.
_what is time anyway???_
For every ID (Refer sprint table), there will be a start time at which an event is started and it will continue to go on. Every LAP is like one task. The difference in `Time` taken between the first LAP and the last lap of particular ID is **Elapsed Time**.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz, [modified the actual question] Posted the sample table (sprint) and expected result. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still is not paying much attention to your sample data, anyway:

```
WITH SpintSummary AS (SELECT SprintEvent, ID, MIN(Time) AS StartTime, MAX(Time) AS EndTime, COUNT(LAP) AS Laps
                      FROM Sprint
                      GROUP BY SprintEvent, ID)
SELECT ss.SprintEvent, n.Name, s.State, ss.Laps, ss.StartTime, ss.EndTime, 
    CASE 
        WHEN e.cnt=0 THEN f.Status 
        ELSE 'Failed' 
    END AS Status, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ss.StartTime, ss.EndTime) AS ElapsedTimeMins
FROM SpintSummary ss
     INNER JOIN dbo.Name n ON n.Id=ss.ID
     INNER JOIN dbo.State s ON s.Id=ss.ID
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM Sprint sp
                 WHERE sp.SprintEvent=ss.SprintEvent AND sp.ID=ss.ID AND sp.LIVEStatus='ERROR') e(cnt)
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(1)FinalStatus
                 FROM Sprint sp
                 WHERE sp.SprintEvent=ss.SprintEvent AND sp.ID=ss.ID
                 ORDER BY sp.Time DESC, LAP DESC) f(Status);
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea7b22a129ae1b91b32e1c655978dc16)

Next time, please try to supply sample data as is in the fiddle.